# Style table row according to data field value

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I have a table in ejs file with data from backend api:

```
<table style="margin-top: 15px" id="importerTable"
                                   class="span11 mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-data-table--selectable mdl-shadow--2dp">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>

                                    <th>MLS ID</th>

                                    <th>Alquiler/Venta</th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <% properties.forEach(function (p) { %>
                                    <tr style ="<%= p.imported != null ?  'background-color: green' : '' %>" >

                                        <td ><%= p.mlsid %></td>
                                        <td ><%= p.transactionType == 1 ? 'Alquiler':  p.transactionType == 2 ? 'Venta' : 'Alquiler Temporario' %></td>

                                        <td>
                                            <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon"
                                                    onclick="showPopup(<%= p.id %>)">
                                                <i class="material-icons">remove_red_eyes</i>
                                            </button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                <% }) %>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

I need to format each row depending of the value of p.imported. I already set a background color for rows where imported value is different from null, but it sets this property to whole table rows. This is what I am getting:

[image]

Comment: Any comment about it?

Comment: Please clarify exactly what you are wanting, you would like to take the imported value, and set it to what exactly?

Comment: The value of imported is correct. I want to set background color green to each row that has imported value different from null.

Comment: So what you have right now is setting the background to the whole row, or what is it not doing correctly?

Comment: I updated the question. As you see it sets bg color to all rows, but not all rows have imported valu different from null

Comment: you should print out the value of `p.imported` in a table cell to debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was setting wrong condition and changed it for
  `<tr style ="<%= p.imported ? 'background-color: green' : '' %>" >`
 So I got this:
[image]